# chrome.tabs.executeScript - how to make a script return a value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, return

I am injecting a script into a tab using [chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript). Its last parameters is a callback function that will be called with `The result of the script in every injected frame.` . How do I make my script return a result? I tried adding a simple return statement at the end of my js, but nothing got returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As RobW corrected me, a function is not necessary, just make sure that the desired data is the last expression and of course that is JSON-serializable.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,
  {code:"document.charset"},
  function(results){
     // results[0] will now contain the charset for the page in question
});
```

Comment: Wrapping in a function is not needed. In order to see some meaningful value at the `executeScript` callback, three requirements need to be satisfied: 1. The correct permissions must be requested via the manifest file 2. The desired result must be the last expression at the end of the whole JavaScript block (function/variable declarations do not count - `1;var x=2;` results in `1`, for instance). 3. The value must be JSON-serializable.

Comment: @RobW Thanks, I had figured a function wasn't needed, but I was too focused on thinking I had to *return* it and didn't try it this way.